# Can't create button in cgridview in yii

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, cgridview

following is my code in view but i am unable to create button in cgridview

```
   <?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
    <div class="search-form" style="display:none">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
'model'=>$model,
      )); ?>
    </div><!-- search-form -->

    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'product-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->countregister($_GET['id']),
'enablePagination' => true,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(

    'name',
    'email',





    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{Register}{update}{view}',

        'buttons'=>array(
               'Register'=>array(
               'label'=>'Register',
               'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('register/create',array(
                'id'=>$_GET['id'],
               'rid'=>$_GET['rid']
               ))
              )
               ),

    ),

    ),
     )); ?>
```

passed rid to query string
 i am getting this error

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d               code on line 1
```

the register button appears with the above error but if click doesnt go to the specified URL

PLEASE  HELP let me know how can i make up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this

```
<?php    $id=$_GET['id'];
            $rid=$_GET['rid'];  ?>
                <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
// rest of your code

'url'=>"Yii::app()->createUrl('register/create',array(
                'id'=>$id,
               'rid'=>$rid
               ))"
```

more details

```
'buttonID' => array
(
    'label'=>'...',     //Text label of the button.
    'url'=>'...',       //A PHP expression for generating the URL of the button.
    'imageUrl'=>'...',  //Image URL of the button.
    'options'=>array(), //HTML options for the button tag.
    'click'=>'...',     //A JS function to be invoked when the button is clicked.
    'visible'=>'...',   //A PHP expression for determining whether the button is visible.
)
```

Comment: not working :( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: the fault is somewhere else in your code  as its working for me very well. please post your full code

Comment: your previous code had was displaying the register button but url was not working  as well showing  error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: It was because your $_GET[] was creating problem. save it another variable and then try. Have updated my code as well

Comment: and what about css i wanna style it as button how, where is it to be done

Comment: i need to pass something like .........'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('register/create',array(
                'email'=>$data->email),
               ) ....... but its not workng :(

Comment: what is not working? does it throw any error? Make sure that your create action accepts $email as parameter AND wrap the Yii::app()->createUrl('register/create',array( 'email'=>$data->email) inside double quotes

Comment: Undefined variable: data

Comment: can you post the full code ? this shows that you are not able to access $data

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, change

```
 'url'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/index.php?r=register/create&id='.$_GET['id'].'&rid='Yii::app()->user->userid))',
```

to:

```
 'url' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/index.php?r=register/create&id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&rid=' . Yii::app()->user->userid)),
```

use a better IDE to help you with this kind of errors

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1